# Frequency-split waveforms

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing, fftw, waveform

I would like to generate waveforms which show the low, mid and high frequencies together: ala traktor for ipad http://www.dawsons.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/TRAKTOR_DJ_main-2_L.jpg

I have managed to get frequency data of the audio using fft, then sum up the amplitudes in the bins based on frequency ranges (low: 0 - 300Hz, mid: 300 - 2000Hz, high: 2000Hz +) but when plotted these do not resemble the usual RMS plot of the same sound.

Can someone please give me a pointer on how the Traktor waveforms are generated?
Many thanks!

Comment: @learnvst is correct that filtering is a better way to do this. But, should you need an FFT in the future, I highly recommend Kiss FFT (http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/files/kissfft/) by Mark Borgerding. It's much much easier to work with than FFTW and more than fast enough for any likely audio application.

Comment: Are you sure that's what traktor is showing? It looks to me like it's showing peak, RMS and something else (abs-mean).

Comment: Im pretty sure the fat low line is the bass, also the out-most looks like RMS. The middle one i assume is the frequencies above bass, but that is an assumption as i have never used the iPad version :)

Comment: The three band rms assumption is correct (pretty obvious) -- plus some special ingredients and tweaking for nicer looks, but that's secret ;)

Comment: Ah Andre, very intriguing! Perhaps you smooth things only if the change is below a threshold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not use FFT data to do such a simple job. Instead, consider running the input signal through 3 simple time domain IIR filters that split the information into low, mid and high signals. This results in 3 time domain signals that are easy to plot. The advantage of this approach is that you do not have to worry about the inverse FFT process that would give you your time domain waveforms from each band. It should also be less processor intensive as you are doing everything in the time domain.

There is some simple code for a 2nd order Butterworth bandpass filter contained in one of my github repos at about line 120 [of this file](https://github.com/audioplastic/BioAid/blob/master/src/algoComponents.hpp) that you are welcome to use as a start point.

Comment: Thanks Nick, i will have a go implementing this :)

Comment: For more on why the FFT is not appropriate: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/why-eq-is-done-in-time-domain.html and a tutorial on basic audio EQ: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/basic-audio-eqs.html

Comment: Nice blog post Bjorn, wish i found it earlier!